# Symfony3 deserialize

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have this entity:

`AppBundle\Entity\Ciudad`

```
class Ciudad{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ComunidadAutonoma")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_ccaa", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $ccaa;
    ....

    public function getCcaa()
    {
        return $this->ccaa;
    }

    public function setCcaa(ComunidadAutonoma $ccaa)
    {
        $this->ccaa = $ccaa;
    }
}
```

And the other entity is:

`AppBundle\Entity\ComunidadAutonoma`

```
class ComunidadAutonoma{
    properties
    getters
    setters
}
```

In a controller, I get data from a form, and I´m triying to deserialize the data into a `Ciudad` entity, but is getting me allways the same error:

`Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\ComunidadAutonoma", "integer" given`

[image]

In the form data I send to the action in  the controller, the value of the comunidadautonoma is the id of the selected option in a combo:

```
{
    parameters...
    ccaa:7,
    parameters...
}
```

In my controller I have this:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use AppBundle\Entity\Ciudad;

class CiudadController extends Controller
{
    public function procesarAction(Request $request)
    {
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $ciudad= $this->serializer->deserialize($parametros['parametros'], Ciudad::class, 'json');
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?Do I need any special configuration to deserializer an entity with a relation?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're talking about a form, but are you using Symfony Forms?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do anything if you properly configured a type. While creating a Form Type for your entity please add class name to your type like:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Ciudad::class,
    ]);
}
```

And please use english naming for your projects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are sending form data to your controller you could use Form Type classes to leverage all the power of the Symfony Form Component that will all this job for you.

Answering your specific question (and assuming you cannot/don't want to use Symfony Form Component) this error is absolutely expected. As you can see in your `setCcaa` function declaration inside `Ciudad` class:

```
public function setCcaa(ComunidadAutonoma $ccaa)
```

Because of the type-hinting (`ComunidadAutonoma $ccaa`) `setCcaa` function expects an argument of type `ComunidadAutonoma`. Now when Symfony serializer tries to denormalize your json object it calls `setCcaa` function with argument the ccaa value provided in your json (in your example is 7) which happens to be an integer. So Symfony complains that you provide an integer instead of `ComunidadAutonoma` type.

In order to solve this problem you have to create and use your own [normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html) so that you can transform this integer to the corresponding entity object from your database. Something like this:

```
class EntityNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    /**
     * Entity manager
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        ?ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null,
        ?NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null,
        ?PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null,
        ?PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($classMetadataFactory, $nameConverter, $propertyAccessor, $propertyTypeExtractor);
        // Entity manager
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return strpos($type, 'App\\Entity\\') === 0 && (is_numeric($data) || is_string($data));
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->em->find($class, $data);
    }
}
```

What this normalizer does is that it checks if your data type (in this case $ccaa) is type of an entity and if the data value provided (in this case 7) is an integer, it transforms this integer to the corresponding entity object from your database (if existing).

To get this normalizer working you should also register it in your services.yaml configuration, with the appropriate tags like this:

```
services:
    App\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer:
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        tags:
            - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

You could also set the normalizer's priority but since the default priority value is equal to 0 when Symfony's built-in normalizers' priority is by default negative, your normalizer will be used first.

You could check a fully explained example of this in this fine [article](https://medium.com/cloudstek/using-the-symfony-serializer-with-doctrine-relations-69ecb17e6ebd).

Comment: Ok,one question and I will try,where should I create this class `EntityNormalizer`?in App?App\Resources\Normalizer?

Comment: I have created into my `AppBundle` a new folder called `Normalizer` and inside this folder I hace created a php class called `EntityNormalizer.php` and generated the service `AppBundle\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer`, and I´m getting the same error

Comment: Did you register the normalizer in services.yaml?

Comment: Yep, I generated the class as mentioned in a previous comment, and added the service in `services.yml` only changing the first line from `App\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer` to `AppBundle\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer`

Comment: You should also add it to your array of normalizers in your controller. Here: $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

Comment: No way, I have added the normalizers `$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(),new EntityNormalizer($em));` and I´m getting the same error

Comment: You should try to clear cache, both php bin/console cache:clear and php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata and try also to change order in your normalizer array: $normalizers = [new EntityNormalizer($em), new ObjectNormalizer()];. The new normalizer doesn't seem to get called at all. If nothing of the above helps, try to debug your normalizer to see if it is actually called.

Comment: Also try to explicitly set the priority of the new normalizer, in your services configuration.